# Ordenar archivos de texto en SSH Putty

Tags: ssh, touch, ordenamiento, mkdir, putty

estoy empezando a manejar SSH (con el programa Putty) desde hace poco y tengo una duda.

He creados un directorio y dentro de él unos archivos de texto (estos solo tienen una palabra dentro de ellos) y ahora lo que tengo que hacer es ordenarlos por orden alfabético, pero tengo que ordenar los archivos, no su contenido (sé que para esto se usa el comando sort) y me preguntaba de que manera puedo hacer que estos archivos se ordenen de dicha manera.

¿Alguien sabe alguna manera de hacerlo?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: ssh es un cliente para sesion remota. Puedes hacer las mismas tareas que haces en  un shell/terminal normal. Pero como tal no puedes "reordenar" los archivos y que se queden asi. Si acaso, puedes seguir usando los comandos normales (sort, como bien dices, hace eso).

Comment: Muchas gracias! ha sido más simple de lo que pensaba.